# Difference between date in miliseconds and its Calendar representation

Tags: java, calendar, timestamp

I have two functions which convert a date String to a date in milliseconds:

```
public static long convertYYYYMMDDtoLong(String date) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    Date d = f.parse(date);
    long milliseconds = d.getTime();
    return milliseconds;
}
```

If I run this function I get the following result:

```
long timeStamp = convertYYYYMMDDtoLong("2014-02-17");
System.out.println(timeStamp);
```

It prints:

```
1389909720000
```

Now, if I run the following code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

It prints out:

```
Fri Jan 17 00:02:00 IST 2014
```

Why is my date shifted by one month? What is wrong?

**P.S:** My problem is that I need to map the date, represented as `long`, to another third party API which accepts `Calendar` format only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `mm`, which is minutes, not months. You want `yyyy-MM-dd` as your format string.

It's not clear why you're not returning a `Calendar` directly from your method, mind you:

```
private static final TimeZone UTC = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC")

public static Calendar convertYYYYMMDDtoCalendar(String text) throws ParseException {        
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    format.setTimeZone(UTC);
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(UTC);
    calendar.setDate(format.parse(text));
    return calendar;
}
```

(That's assuming you want a time zone of UTC... you'll need to decide that for yourself.)